# HDMI output doesn't fit the TV screen

Tags: drivers, display, hdmi, display-resolution, vga

I am using an Acer Aspire R7-372T laptop with Philips 42pf5421/10 TV using HDMI. The TV seems to support a 1920x1080 resolution but when I set that, the display is cropped about 10-20 pixels in all four directions, so it's basically zoomed a bit.

I tried using windows 10 and setting the resolution to 1920x1080, and it works, even though not all pixels on the screen are utilised, about 10 on top and 10 on the bottom are black, so I guess the display is a bit scaled, but I can see the full display of the system.

How can I configure Ubuntu to behave like Windows in this case?

UPDATE: it seems that when using windows, the TV is in "PC Mode", but when using Ubuntu it's in "HD Mode". Is it possible to configure the display driver in Ubuntu so that it triggers the TV to be in "PC Mode" so that the displayed is scaled properly? I can't change those modes on the TV myself using the remote control.

Comment: Normally you would have to change the setting on the tv (at least the tv model I have). Sometimes you can compensate using an overscan option but although it might use the whole screen the actual image gets somewhat distorted. You should try getting the tv option into something called pc-mode or scan-only. Probably easy to find if you search how to do it for your model. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the option can also be called Just Scan on your tv. Check the link below for some extra menu images on how to find it.

https://www.katescomment.com/tv-monitor-how-to-fix-overscan-zoom/comment-page-1/

Good luck!